how can I fix this routing issue in Apache?
I have an issue about my php and vue js project. When I have this .htaccess file configuration:
RewriteEngine On

# Deliver the folder or file directly if it exists on the server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Redirect every request to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

The database connection is ok, and also there are no CORS errors at all. But when I reload /add-product page it gives me a 404 error.
When I searched about this issue I fixed it with this .htaccess file configuration:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>

With this configuration the page reloading is fixed but now I am getting a CORS error. How can I fix it? What can be the issue?
This is my php router:
<?php

namespace App;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 0); 

use App\Controllers\ProductController;
use App\Models\Products;
use App\Utils\Headers;
use Bramus\Router\Router;
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

class App
{
    private static function setRoutes(): void
    {
        $router = new Router();

        $productModel = new Products();
        $productController = new ProductController($productModel);

        $router->get('/products', [$productController, 'getProducts']);
        $router->post('/create-product', [$productController, 'createProduct']);
        $router->post('/mass-delete', [$productController, 'deleteProducts']);

        $router->run();
    }

    private static function loadEnvVariables()
    {
        $dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__));
        $dotenv->safeLoad();
    }

    public static function run()
    {
        Headers::set();
        self::loadEnvVariables();
        self::setRoutes();
    }
}


"what can be issue?" - you are rewriting all the requests that do not map onto an existing file or folder, to the index.html now. The routes you have set up in your PHP, do also not map onto an existing file or folder - so those need to be rewritten to the index.php, otherwise PHP doesn't get involved here any more in the first place. But that rewrite doesn't happen any more now, due to the change you made.

and how can i fix it?

It seems you have a conflict between the requirements for your frontend (vueJS) routing and the requirements for your backend (PHP) routing. Possibly you should host frontend and backend in different environments, or at very least in different folders and/or subdomains where you can define different htaccess rules for them.
